# Unwanted box shadow appearing on website and responsive break

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, box-shadow

I am currently updating/working on this web page "https://www.emergencydentalservice.com/emergency-dentist-by-city" and their is an unwanted box shadow appearing in the body that I can not determine from where or why. On top of the unwanted shadow the site also seems to break after 768px and I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you all. [Image of the site breaking after 768px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc0Ta.jpg)

Comment: You need to be more specific about your question. Its hard for anyone to answer your question. It could be so many things.

Answer (score 1):

You have a box shadow set to `#inside-main` on `eds_main.css`.

```
#inside-main {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 1px -2px 4px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -2px 4px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px -2px 4px #666;
    -o-box-shadow: 1px -2px 4px #666;
}
```

becomes

```
#inside-main {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As for the layout breaking, you have `#foot-de-eds, #foot-top-cites` on `eds_main.css` set to:

```
#foot-de-eds, #foot-top-cites {
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1028px;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

Try removing the `max-width: 1028px;` - so:

```
#foot-de-eds, #foot-top-cites {
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the shadow issue:
`#inside-main` still has a box-shadow property on it from `eds_main.css`.

Though you didn't really specify which shadows you do and don't want... as there are multiple on the page.

Inspect Element / Dev Tools is your friend. Makes it easy to hunt down properties you may be overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

on `<div class="phone-wrap">`

remove

```
background: url(/eds_siteIMGS/phoneBG_seperated.png) repeat-x;
```

The image have shadow